# Meta analysing outcomes with different definitions?

Tags: meta-analysis

I'm looking at meta analysing a set of studies that report adverse events and was wondering if it makes sense to synthesise these outcomes if they measure the same adverse event defined in different ways.

For example, two sets of studies with binomial outcomes, some defining an event as just an occurrence and some using a questionnaire to measure the severity of an occurrence and tallying based on whether the severity is above a certain score.

Any advice would be highly appreciated thanks!

Comment: If they're measured in different ways, they aren't directly comparable. Meta analysis is for outcomes that *are* directly comparable. You could instead just report on both ways in which studies measure the outcome and see if they come to the same conclusion or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you include studies with different ways of estimating the presence of an event then you are making the assumption that they come to the same ting. So for example if the adverse event is pain at the injection site and some just ask whether the patient experienced it while other rate it on a four point scale from 0 to 3 and then choose 2 and 3 as present the assumption is that people just asked about pain would not have reported a mild pain.

If you are willing to make that assumption then you can combine them but I would suggest it is close to mandatory to include a moderator for method to see if they differ.

A much bigger issue, in my opinion, is whether the adverse events were elicited or spontaneously reported. That can make a huge difference.